# JSON Parse Error "TypeError: undefined is not an object" "[object Object]

Tags: javascript, api, rest, jsonparser

I been trying to JSONParse this rest api, but haven't had any luck. Would anyone be able to see why I keep getting either [object Object] or undefined error?

```
    <div id="store_1_name"></div> 
    <div id="owner_1_name"></div>
    <div id="friend_1_name"></div>

var raw_data_string = '{"2":[{"buy":[{"house":"loan","condo":{"USD":64311.9005450},"apartment":{}},{"house":"rent","condo":{"USD":2015.38570},"apartment":{}}]}';

var data = JSON.parse(raw_data_string);

for (var i in data) {
  ParseUpdate(data[i].house, data[i].condo, data[i].apartment);
}

function ParseUpdate(house, condo, aparment) {


  var house = data[i].house;
  var condo = data[i].condo;
  var apartment = data[i].buy.apartment;
}


document.getElementById("store_1_name").innerHTML = data[0].house;
document.getElementById("owner_1_name").innerHTML = data[0].condo;
document.getElementById("friend_1_name").innerHTML = data[0].apartment;
```

Thanks all!

Comment: What is ParseUpdate supposed to do? Right now, it does nothing.

Comment: I think `for (var i in data)` followed by `data[i]` looks wrong, but I can't help much because I don't know what your code is supposed to do. Could you add a description of the expected behavior along with the complete error message?

Comment: Your `raw_data_string` is not a valid JSON string

Comment: See [How to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing so many things wrong here. 1st, the JSON string is invalid. 2nd, You're trying to access wrong elements inside the `for` loop. 3rd, `data[i].buy.apartment` doesn't exist if you're also accessing `data[i].house` in the same loop as they are inside the same object which is `buy`. 4th, you're trying to show JSON object in the `innerHTML` of a div where you should access the string value you want to show or `stringify` the whole object.

```js
var raw_data_string = '{"2":[{"buy":[{"house":"loan","condo":{"USD":64311.9005450},"apartment":{}},{"house":"rent","condo":{"USD":2015.38570},"apartment":{}}]}]}';

var data = JSON.parse(raw_data_string)[2][0]['buy'];
for (var i in data) {
  ParseUpdate(data[i].house, data[i].condo, data[i].apartment);
}

function ParseUpdate(house, condo, aparment) {
  var house = data[i].house;
  var condo = data[i].condo;
  var apartment = data[i].apartment;
}

document.getElementById("store_1_name").innerHTML = data[0].house;
document.getElementById("owner_1_name").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data[0].condo);
document.getElementById("friend_1_name").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data[0].apartment);
```

```html
<div id="store_1_name"></div> 
    <div id="owner_1_name"></div>
    <div id="friend_1_name"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This help me fix my issue. I didn't realize you have to add the array info after JSON.parse[raw_data_string)
Once I fixed the JSON data, it worked perfect! thanks all.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer and upvote it if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

1. Your json string invalid
2. Check your `data` struct and correct the loop again (`for`)
3. `apartment` is an object but you show it same `string`
   `document.getElementById("friend_1_name").innerHTML = data[0].apartment;` will not work

Answer (score 0):

```
var raw_data_string =
  '{"2":[{"buy":[{"house":"loan","condo":{"USD":64311.9005450},"apartment":{}},{"house":"rent","condo":{"USD":2015.38570},"apartment":{}}]}]}';

var data = JSON.parse(raw_data_string);

console.log(data);
```

There were some missing closing brackets in the raw_data_string. I would suggest [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).